# How to create screen saver (having Constantly change able data based on subscriptions) in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, screensaver, observer-pattern

I need to create a screen saver (a window that's continuously changing its contents) in C#.

The window will have to subscribe to a remote server over the web, which will update the window's contents based on subscriptions.

Do I need to implement Observer pattern for this, or some other mechanism?

I want to implement a FOREX trading application which will subscribe to some stream pricing server and get the updates of prices on the basis of subscriptions.

Windows needs to connect and subscribe to the pricing server first, based on the subscription the prices should be updated accordingly.

After clicking on some price an internet browser should be opened and should show the trading platform to place a trade over there.

Comment: the window content will be updated by your UI logic not by the server, your business logic will poll the server to detect changes. the paradigm is like the Observer but it also depends on the way the server is done and if it allows you to really subscribe or get notified on changes...

Comment: This is a bit vague quite honestly to really answer.  What have you done so far?

Comment: That said, MVVM would have your Model handle the retrieval of the data (however that works in your situation) and the View update the UI, with the ViewModel essentially playing man-in-the-middle to communicate the subscription updates from the Model to the View.

Comment: @itsmatt A service would retrieve the data; not the Model IMHO

Comment: @Aaron - yeah, you are correct here on that point.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a pub-sub system like [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) to have your server able to push updates to your clients without having to run a polling mechanism yourself.

SignalR has a great sample stock ticker that does this.  It works with both web and Windows clients (.NET).

SignalR is open source on github, so you can inspect it as well to learn about how the implement and follow the Observer pattern.